# Rank of the 2-cover space of a knot space

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

It is well known that the order of the first homology group of the double branched cover of a knot $K$ in $S^3$ is the determinant of $K$,   i.e.  $\lvert H_1(B_2(K),\mathbb{Z}) \rvert = \det (K)$.  However, I did not find a formula for its rank. Does anyone know the answer to this question?

Comment: What is " determinant of K"? What is "B_2(k)"?

Comment: No answer for @AnubhavMukherjee ? Here is some possibly relevant material but your question is quite obscure to me: https://web.northeastern.edu/beasley/MATH7375/Lecture23.pdf

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee In "An introduction to knot theory" by Lickorish, p. 99, the determinant of a link $L$ is $\lvert \Delta_L(-1)\rvert$, where $\Delta_L$ is the Alexander polynomial, or equivalently $\lvert\det G\rvert$, where $G$ is a Goeritz matrix associated to a double branched cover of $L$. Presumably $B_2(K)$ is a double branched cover based on the context, but that ought to be clarified.

Comment: @kyle although I'm familiar with knot theory, but still I didn't get the question after reading those notations. The op should elaborate those. Anyway thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: Why was this question closed? It is a perfectly valid question. It seems that the relevant knot theory terms are not widely known to the community, but it's not the OP's job to teach them knot theory.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *Thanks to Sucharit Sarkar for pointing out I was spreading misinformation.  This replaces my previous answer completely.*

The first homology of the double branched cover of a knot in $S^3$ is a finite abelian group.  Since it has no free part, its rank is $0$.

Presumably you meant the minimal number of generators, which is much more interesting.  I'm aware of some things you can say in terms of Fitting/elementary ideals, where the Alexander polynomial is the GCD of the zeroth one.

By considering the relationships between double branched covers $B_2(K)$, two-fold covers of the knot complement $X_2(K)$ and the infinite cyclic cover of the knot complement $X_\infty(K)$, it is possible to work out with some long exact sequences that
$$H_1(B_2(K)) \cong \frac{H_1(X_\infty(K))}{(t^2-1)H_1(X_\infty(K))}$$
where $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$ acts on $H_1(X_\infty(K))$ through deck transformations, with $t$ being the meridian generator of $H_1(S^3-K)$.

Now, a fact about $H_1(X_\infty(K))$ is that $1-t$ acts on it invertibly (explained by Milnor in "Infinite cyclic coverings").  Thus,
$$H_1(B_2(K)) \cong \frac{H_1(X_\infty(K))}{(t+1)H_1(X_\infty(K))}.$$
So, if you take a presentation matrix for $H_1(X_\infty(K))$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$-module, you can substitute in $t=-1$ to get a presentation matrix for $H_1(B_2(K))$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  (A *Goeritz matrix* is an example of such a presentation matrix.)

This is why $\lvert H_1(B_2(K))\rvert = \lvert\Delta_K(-1)\rvert$. There is a square presentation matrix for $H_1(X_\infty(K))$ from the Seifert form, and the Alexander polynomial is the determinant of this.  Plugging in $-1$ gives the determinant of the corresponding square presentation matrix for $H_1(B_2(K))$.  Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, the determinant of the presentation matrix is the order of the module; this is due to Smith normal form having the same determinant, up to multiplication by $-1$.

The Alexander polynomial actually comes from a sequence of polynomials $\Delta^0_K(t),\Delta^1_K(t),\dots$, each dividing the previous, where $\Delta_K(t)=\Delta^0_K(t)$ is the *zeroth* (sometimes *first*, depending on the convention) *Alexander polynomial*, all defined up to multiplication by $\pm t^{k}$.  The polynomial $\Delta^i_K(t)$ is the GCD of the $i$th *Fitting ideal* of $H_1(X_\infty(K))$ (in knot theory literature, it is the $(i-1)$th *elementary ideal*), which is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$.  See chapter 20 of Eisenbud's "Commutative algebra" for more details about Fitting ideals.  The $i$th Fitting ideal for $H_1(X_\infty(K))$ is generated by the $(m-i)\times(m-i)$ minors of the $m\times m$ presentation matrix for $H_1(X_\infty(K))$.  Hence, the $i$th Fitting ideal for $H_1(B_2(K))$ (an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$) is given by the same-sized minors of the same presentation matrix with $t=-1$.

Let's call $\beta^i_K\in\mathbb{Z}$ the GCD (i.e., since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, the generator) of the $i$th Fitting ideal of $H_1(B_2(K))$.  One fact about Fitting ideals is that if $H_1(B_2(K)) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}/m_i\mathbb{Z}$ with $m_{i-1}\mid m_i$ for all $1<i\leq n$, then $\beta^i_K=m_1m_2\dots m_{n-i}$.  Hence, $\beta^0_K=\lvert H_1(B_2(K))\rvert$, and the smallest $i$ such that $\beta^i_K=1$ gives exactly the minimum number of generators for $H_1(B_2(K))$.

To be clear, GCD for $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$ means to take the smallest principal ideal containing the ideal generated by the given set of polynomials.  From this, one may deduce that $\Delta^i_K(-1)$ divides $\beta^i_K$ (and it may be that they are equal, but that seems unlikely).  Thus, the smallest $i$ such that $\Delta^i_K(-1)=1$ gives a lower bound for the number of generators for $H_1(B_2(K))$.

Ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$ are of the form $(p(t),n)$ for $p(t)\in\mathbb{Z}[t]$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, possibly with $p(t)=0$ or $n=0$.  If this is the $i$th Fitting ideal of $H_1(X_\infty(K))$, then the corresponding Fitting ideal for $H_1(B_2(K))$ would be $(p(-1),n)$.  Then $\beta^i_K$ is the GCD of $p(-1)$ and $n$.  While the gcd of $p(t)$ and $n$ might be $1$, it might be that the gcd of $p(-1)$ and $n$ is bigger than $1$.

The zeroth Fitting ideal of $H_1(X_\infty(K))$ is principal since the presentation matrix is square, so $\beta^0_K=\Delta^0_K(-1)$.  This is restating that $\lvert H_1(B_2(K)) \rvert=\lvert\beta^0_K\rvert = \lvert \Delta_K(-1)\rvert$.

The Alexander polynomials of the knot $8_{20}$ are
\begin{align}
\Delta^0_{8_{20}}(t) &= (1-3t+t^2)(1-t+t^2)^2 \\
\Delta^1_{8_{20}}(t) &= 1-t+t^2 \\
\Delta^2_{8_{20}}(t) &= 1
\end{align}
Since $\Delta^1_{8_{20}}(-1)=3$, we know that $H_1(B_2(8_{20}))$ needs at least two generators.

I happen to know that
$$ H_1(X_\infty(8_{20})) = \mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]/((1-3t+t^2)(1-t+t^2)) \oplus \mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]/(1-t+t^2) $$
Hence, $H_1(B_2(8_{20})) = \mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.  That's two generators.

While the Alexander polynomials detected the number of generators in this case, consider $9_{46}$.  It has
$$ H_1(X_\infty(9_{46})) = \mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]/(2-t)\oplus \mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]/(1-2t) $$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\Delta^0_{9_{46}}(t) &= (2-t)(1-2t) \\
\Delta^1_{9_{46}}(t) &= 1 \\
\end{align}
Since $\Delta^0_{9_{46}}(-1)=9$ and $\Delta^1_{9_{46}}(-1)=1$, we know $H_1(B_2(9_{46}))$ has at least one generator.  However, $\beta^0_{9_{46}}=9$, $\beta^1_{9_{46}}=3$, and $\beta^2_{9_{46}}=1$, so it needs exactly two generators.

One more knot: $6_1$.  It has the exact same Alexander polynomials as $9_{46}$.  However, $\beta^1_{6_1}=1$.  Therefore, $6_1$ and $9_{46}$ can be distinguished by this piece of homological information about their double branched covers.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kyle Miller! I was not aware of the fact that H_1(B_2(K),\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/(\Delta_K(-1)). However, I am confused here - if the rank is 1 - then the B_2(K)  can not be a homology sphere unless det(K)=1. It is known (Milnor proved it) thet B_2(T(p,q)) is the Brieskorn homology sphere $\Sigma (p,q,2)$.  This contradicts this formula.  Reference  https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/milnbries.pdf

Comment: This puzzle you present took a while to pin down, but if I'm not mistaken, the paper says it is a homology sphere in the case that both $p$ and $q$ are odd. The determinant of $T(2r+1,2s+1)$ is $1$ by my calculations via the Alexander polynomial.  (Chapter 9 of Lickorish's book "An Introduction to Knot Theory" discusses the homology of cyclic branched covers, if you want a reference.)

Comment: I am confused. I think the branched double cover of a connected sum of two knots is the connected sum of the two individual branched double covers, and so the first homology is the direct sum. For instance, the first homology for the branched double cover of trefoil is $Z/3$, so the first homology of the branched double cover of connected sum of two trefoils should be $Z/3 \oplus Z/3$.

Comment: @SucharitSarkar You're entirely right, and my answer is complete nonsense.  The double branched cover's $H_1$ is presented by a presentation matrix for the Alexander module ($H_1$ of the infinite cyclic cover as a module over $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$) evaluated at $t=-1$.  The connect sum of knots has a block diagonal presentation matrix for its Alexander module, hence the $H_1$ is a direct sum.  (Also, the *rank* of a finite abelian group is $0$.  More interesting would be the minimal number of generators, but I'm not sure what's known about that.)

Comment: @SucharitSarkar I completely reworked the answer and added an example of a prime knot that contradicts my original claim.  Thanks

Comment: Alexander and Briggs pointed out long ago that 6_1 and 9_46 are distinguished by the homology of their double branched covers -- Z9 vs. Z3xZ3.  These groups are easily calculated from the standard Wirtinger cellular decomposition of such covers. --Ken Perko, lbrtpl@gmail.com.

Comment: @user43408 Hi Ken, I'm not sure what point you're making exactly -- it's certainly easy to calculate the homologies of the double branched covers (and indeed, that's more or less how I calculated the Alexander polynomials), but the point of the $6_1$ example was to show a case where a higher Alexander polynomial can show the ranks of the homologies are different.

Comment: OK, Kyle. It just seems to me that resorting to higher polynomials to distinguish these easy homologies is doing it the hard way. My high school math teacher taught us that "the good mathematician is the lazy mathematician."  --Ken Perko