# Show that the two-fold cyclic branched cover of a knot $K $ with trivial Alexander polynomial is a homology sphere.

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I meet this when reading a paper about cyclic branched covering spaces of knots. There is no explanation nearby, can anyone tell me how to understand this?

Comment: The first homology of the double branched cover of a knot has order equal to the absolute value of the Alexander polynomial evaluated at $-1$, so if the Alexander polynomial is trivial, the first homology is trivial. (I happened to write about some of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867440/rank-of-the-2-cover-space-of-a-knot-space/2867543#2867543) in case it's helpful.)

Comment: The argument in the link is indeed much more profound and wide. Maybe after choosing a proper basis for the Seifert surface, then compute the M-V sequence consisting of two copies of the complement of the Seifert surface in $S^3$. The free $S^1$ cycle is eliminated by the attaching solid torus, thus the rank of the first homology group of the cyclic double branched cover is zero. The abstract value of the determinant of presentation matrix is just the order of $H_1(\Sigma_2(K))$, which can be seen to equal $|\Delta_K(-1)|$ under the properly chosen basis.